# Screen scapingin in php using file_get_contents

Tags: php, screen, screen-scraping

Hi I am very new to screen scraping. I am trying to scrape reviews from a hotel booking webite to display on to mine..

Ive got this far but got a bit stuck. Can anyone help?

```
<?php 
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.laterooms.com/en/hotel-reviews/238902_the-westfield-bb-sandown.aspx');
$regex = '/<div id="summary">
(.+?)</div>/';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
var_dump($match); 
echo $match[1];
?>
```

Comment: Ask them for an API, otherwise they probably don't want you taking their reviews.

Comment: screen-scraping is **NOT** a good idea..the content in the website you are scraping keeps changing constantly in terms of semantics and internals and your site will break all over the place, making it look really bad. Additionally you can have legal issues. Better look for sites/services with APIs or RSS or someother ways of syndication as Jleagle suggested.

Comment: The canonical answer for anything relating to html + regexes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068

Comment: I am an affiliate of this website. Their api currently doesnt support guest reviews and I have permission to scrape I just dont know how to do it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Screen scrape using php and fopen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957038/screen-scrape-using-php-and-fopen)

Answer (score 1):

use [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
<?php
  define('URL', 'http://www.laterooms.com/en/hotel-reviews/238902_the-westfield-bb-sandown.aspx');
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents(URL));
  $summary = $doc->getElementById('summary');
  // also have $doc->getElementsByTagName , etc
  var_export($summary);
?>
```

Also, for more complicated queries you should consider looking into [XPATH](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) (uses jQuery-like syntax)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Seem this returns several errors: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 9 in /homepages/************/hotel.php on line 377Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 9 in /homepages/28/d282373443/htdocs/eurobooker/hotel.php on line 377

Comment: DOMElement::__set_state(array( ))

Comment: depends if the file you are loading has errors or not. There are different load methods: loadHTML, loadXML, load. Check them out and try the simple examples and see if that is the functionality you need. When you get a grip of it you can apply it on a real-live webpage

Generally though, it has to be valid HTML for it to wark

Comment: I changed it to load.. there are no errors now.. it just prints NULL